# Distress firms and cross section returns

Tags: asset-pricing, expected-return

In George and Hwang's 2010 JFE paper, they are trying to resolve the so called distress risk and leverage puzzles. This is their explanation:

> This is a puzzle because high distress intensity or
>   nearness to default means the firm has exhausted its
>   capacity to issue low-risk debt.Since leverage amplifies
>   the exposure of equity to priced systematic risks,firms
>   with high distress measures should be those for which
>   equity exposures are most amplified.

How does leverage amplify the exposure of equity to priced systematic risks? Can someone please elaborate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes leverage amplifies the exposure of equity to systematic risks.

Just consider the standard textbook formula (Modigliani-Miller):

$\beta_e = \beta_a \times (1+\frac{D(1-\tau)}{V})$
where $\beta_e$ is the sensitivity of the stock to systematic risk, $\tau$ is the tax-rate and $D/V$ is the leverage ratio.

So beta (i.e. the exposure to systematic risk) increases with leverage. If we use Harris-Pringle or Milles-Ezzel formulas we get a similar result.